# Intermediate arithmetic results in F_1 geometry

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, field-with-one-element

Much is made of the search for a proof of the Riemann hypothesis via the field with one element. Are there any lesser classic arithmetic results that have been proved with F_1 geometry, such as the prime number theorem? Do any such proofs seem within reach of current models of F_1 geometry?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the answer is a resounding *no*

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23394/applications-of-algebraic-geometry-over-a-field-with-one-element

Comment: Thanks for the link! I didn't know whether things had changed in the last ten or so years since that question...