# Are there F_un Lie algebras ?  

Tags: field-with-one-element, rt.representation-theory

**Background** See [WP-article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element) on F_1 = F_{un} = Field with one element (and also [this MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2300/what-is-the-field-with-one-element) question). Paraphrasing someone:
we do not know what is it, but it is not a field :). For this question it is enough to keep in mind J. Tits idea (1957) that Weyl groups should be thought as semisimple groups over F_1.
E.g. symmetric group S_n = GL_n(F_1).

**Q1** What might be Lie algebras over F_1 ? In particular for GL_n ?
What numerology should correspond to gl_n(F_1) ? I.e. are there some numbers related to
gl_n(F_q) which have a limit when q->1 (may be renormalized like with GL_n(F_q)) ?

---

Comments on further questions are also welcome:

**Q2** To what extent representation theory of S_n can be thought as limit q->1 of representation theory of GL_n(F_q) ? (There is some [paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/126_fall_98/papers/dgharris.pdf) "Translating the Irreducible Representations of S_n into GL_n(F_q)", but I do not quite understand it).

**Q3** What might be "orbit method" to construct representations of S_n = GL_n(F_1) ?

**Q4** What might be Langlands correspondence over F_1 ? Should it be related to bijection between
irreps of S_n and its conj. classes (keep in mind that GL^L=GL).

Comment: Lie algebras in characteristic p are already bad enough, and capture so little of the group situation. E.g. a function on the line that's invariant under translation (a group action) must be constant, but a function with derivative zero (the Lie algebra action) is merely required to be a polynomial in x^p. If p=1, this looks like no condition at all...?

Comment: @Allen thank you, it is very valuable comment... may be one should ask about huger algebra including d_x^p/p! ("divided differences" its name if I remember correctly)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will only attempt to answer the first question.

$n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbf{F}_1$ is the same as a pointed set with $n+1$ elements. It is natural to call $GL_n(\mathbf{F}_1)$ the group of automorphisms of $\mathbf{F}_1^n$ and $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbf{F}_1)$ the monoid of endomorphisms. There are at least two notions of morphisms:

1. Plain morphisms of pointed sets. The monoid of endomorphisms has cardinality $(n+1)^n$.
2. Maps of pointed sets which are injective if you throw away the basepoints (see http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0912). It is not too hard to see that the cardinality of $End(\mathbf{F}_1)$ is
   $$\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ k\end{array}\right)\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(n!)^2}{k!(n-k)!^2}.$$
   Here $k$ is the number of elements that don't go to the basepoint.

Note, that in both cases the group of automorphisms is the same ($S_n$).

Comment: This is nicer to think of as the monoids of partial transformations and of partial permutations of an n-element set by dropping the base point. They are called the full partial transformation monoid and the symmetric inverse monoid (or rook monoid) respectively. 